# import Foundation changes behaviors of arithmetic operators

Tags: swift

```
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
   1> 1 / 3.0
$R0: Double = 0.33333333333333331
   2> 1 % 3
$R1: Int = 1
   3> 1 % 3 / 3.0
$R2: Double = 0.33333333333333331

   4> import Foundation
   5> 1 / 3.0
$R3: Double = 0.33333333333333331
   6> 1 % 3
$R4: Int = 1
   7> 1 % 3 / 3.0
$R5: Int = 0    // this result changes after importing Foundation
```

Is this a bug or some kind of implicit conversion magic in Swift?

### Edit

Another (simpler) way to reproduce this issue:

```
  1> 1.0 / 3
$R0: Double = 0.33333333333333331
  2> import Foundation
  3> 1.0 / 3
$R1: Int = 0
  4> Double(1.0) / 3    // this is a workaround
$R2: Double = 0.33333333333333331
```

I can reproduce this issue in an iOS app, not just from the REPL. I am using xcode6-beta5.

Comment: Interesting that I can't seem to replicate it outside the playground or REPL. Build a trivial Mac app, with or without Foundation imported, and you get the expected behaviour.

Comment: I can reproduce it in an iOS app. That's how I found this issue initially. My original code is `Int(arc4random()) % 100 / 100.0` which is always evaluated to 0. I'm the OP, not the other Ethan whose comments said he couldn't reproduce this issue.

Comment: Are you running that code on a 32-bit target? Because you'll have some other problems with that. arc4random() returns 32-bit unsigned; on a 32-bit platform Int is 32-bit signed, so things will get messy. I'd use `Double(arc4random_uniform(100)) / 100.0`; that'll avoid [modulo bias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator), too. Also: Oddly, I can reproduce your problem with arc4random in the same project where `1 % 3 / 3.0` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Without Foundation, these two expressions return different types:

```
1 % 3 / 3     // 0 : Int
1 % 3 / 3.0   // 0.33333333333 : Double
```

This agrees with the behaviour defined in the Swift book:

> “If you combine integer and floating-point literals in an expression, a type of Double will be inferred from the context:”

With Foundation, the expressions both return an Integer:

```
1 % 3 / 3     // 0 : Int
1 % 3 / 3.0   // 0 : Int
```

Having investigated, I can't see anything obvious in Foundation that would cause this—there's no strange operators defined for % or / that would do this, and the precedence seems the same. Not only that, but I can't reproduce the behaviour outside a playground or the REPL. If you do the above in a simple console app, then you see the expected (0.333333333333333: Double) result even if you import Foundation.

As Zaph says, this is almost certainly a bug. I'd report it.

Comment: I files a Radar on this.

Comment: It certainly seems unexpected. Be nice to track down which bit of Foundation is doing it for the bug report, though.

Comment: If you track it down file a radar the reference me in a comment with the info/Radar# and I will update.

Comment: @Zaph Couldn't find it—in fact, I'm pretty sure my original guess, of a rogue operator, is not there to be found. If you build actual apps—OS X or iOS—you can't reproduce the problem by importing Foundation. I'm starting to suspect that the bug might be in the Playground/REPL evaluation/printing code, or somewhere like that. But I think it's time to give up poking and leave it to the experts.

Comment: ic.  Well... in playground it doesn't seem to have this problem, and when I run it, I don't have the problem either.  But yea, beta.

Comment: @Ethan Odd. If I put `import Foundation; 1 % 3 / 3.0` into a new Playground, I get 0. If I delete the `import Foundation` I get `0.333333333333333`.

Answer (score 0):

I played around in playground to try to replicate your problem but was unnable.  I tried this...

```
let r7 = 1 % 3 / 3.0 //evaluates to 0.333333

import Foundation

let r8 = 1 % 3 / 3.0 //evaluates to 0.333333
```

I think possibly what you are seeing is a difference in assigning the RHS to an explicit type Double vs type Int variable on the LHS.  So ...

```
let r5:Double = 1 % 3 / 3.0 //evaluates to 0.33333
let r6:Int = 1 % 3 / 3.0 //evaluates to 0
```

I find this mathematic expression to be slightly ambiguous also, to different readers.  It may be smart to rewrite it as *(1%3)/3.0* (if that is infact what you meant!! that's what the computer sees).  Of course the result of 1%3 is the integer 1.  The integer 1 divided by the Double 3.0 equals 0.33333.  So I feel like your problem can be reduced to ...

```
let r5:Double = 0.3333333 //evaluates to 0.33333
let r6:Int = 0.3333333 //evaluates to 0
```

Which doesn't have much to do with arithmetic, just the differences in types Int and Double.

Comment: I can replicate it in a playground, but not by importing Foundation inline. My guess would be that importing Foundation anywhere in a playground imports it for the whole playground.

Comment: It looks like the OP is using Swift from the Terminal. It also looks like importing `Foundation` changed the way the expression was handles, in the first instance as floating point, in the second as integer. I can reproduce it in Terminal—exactly.

Comment: If that were true wouldn't I see r5 = 0, r6 = 0 ??  Please show ur code.

Comment: @Ethan There is no code. Run Swift in the terminal: '/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift' and make the entries in the question. My result: "7> 1 % 3 / 3.0" "$R5: Int = 0"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that Swift is broken, it is Beta after all. I filed a bug report with Apple, Radar: 17962491.